# JQuery Wrap Does not Effect because Blocked by CSS

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am working with a wordpress site with a slider plugin. Orbit SLider. THe site is http://avonmore.ac.nz/.

I'm trying to figure out how to put a link on each slider image using jquery code. The code below is successfully working. However, there is a wrapper that does not allow the slider to be clicked. In-short, the anchor tag cant be clicked even I use z-index and relative position for the images.

jQuery code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.slide-slide.slide-content-1702').wrap("<a class='slider-image' href='<?php echo home_url(); ?>/courses/freight-warehousing/'></a>");
    jQuery('.slide-slide.slide-content-1700').wrap("<a class='slider-image' href='<?php echo home_url(); ?>/courses/hairdressing/'></a>");
 });
```

**Q: How can I make the links unblocked by the SLIDER WRAPPER?**

Comment: try removing the space between the class elements `.slide-slide .slide-content-1702`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div that is causing a problem with the z-index setting is '#orbit-inside'. The z-index setting on this div needs to be 0 or above for the link to work. Also to make the whole slider clickable you will want to wrap both the '.slide-slide' and 'slide-content' elements.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.slide-slide.slide-content-1702').parent().wrapInner("<a class='slider-image' href='<?php echo home_url(); ?>/courses/freight-warehousing/'></a>");
    jQuery('.slide-slide.slide-content-1700').parent().wrapInner("<a class='slider-image' href='<?php echo home_url(); ?>/courses/hairdressing/'></a>");
});
```

Also you might want to change the css settings for '#orbit-inside a' to the following:

```
#orbit-inside a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #333333;
}
```

The only issue now is that the [background image](http://avonmore.ac.nz/wp-content/themes/canvas/images/bg_w_top.png) you applied to div #wrapper is being overlapped. You could resolve this by making a separate div for the background image and then use a combination of z-index and position: absolute; to position it correctly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you're after I think you just need to remove `.slide-slide` from your jQuery() as looking through your url I don't see that element.

To do it a slightly different way we can assume that because the links are being put on via jQuery they don't need to be indexed (SEO). So you could just try binding a click to the .slide-content-x, .slide-slide or parent element and change the window location?

Using: `http://avonmore.ac.nz/`?

```
$( '#orbit-inside' ).on( 'click', '.slide-content', function() {
    var url = 'http://avonmore.ac.nz/';

    if ( $( this ).hasClass( '.slide-content-1700' ) ) {
        url += '/courses/hairdressing/';
    }

    if ( $( this ).hasClass( '.slide-content-1702' ) ) {
        url += '/courses/freight-warehousing/';
    }

    if ( url != 'http://avonmore.ac.nz/' ) {
        // Make sure something was set
        window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```